# .NET/IIS friendly in-memory antivirus scanning

Tags: asp.net, iis, antivirus

I'm looking for a solution that would let me scan files on the fly. It would need to integrate nicely with either with IIS(6.0 or 7.0) or ASP.NET. I spent some time trying to find something on the Internet but unfortunately all I've found is a COM based solution that still forces me to save files on disk (http://www.opswat.com/metascan.shtml)
Update:
The solution needs to be hosted internally.

Thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 1):

We use [Sophos Anti-Virus Interface](http://www.sophos.com/products/enterprise/email/security-and-control/integration/) (SAVI), an in-process COM-based solution which you can access using COM interop, which does support in-memory scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Metascan REST server or buffer scan of Metascan? I am pretty sure you can pass the byte array to Metascan to scan it.  According to their sample codes, it looks like this.

byte [] buff;
...
...
metaScanLib.Scan(buff);

Answer (score 0):

http://housecall.trendmicro.com/ ?

Comment: I was thinking about but unfortunatelly this kind of tools don't scan files on the fly. What is more this needs to be a solution that is  hosted internally.